# HTML, PHP LEER IMAGENES DE UN FTP

Tags: php, html5, ftp

Tengo un dominio en el cual en la carpeta public_html tengo mi pagina web pero en el mismo dominio tengo un ftp donde tengo imágenes donde los clientes las suben y necesito leer esa carpeta pero no puedo, ya intente moverme al directorio  que necesitó y no puedo también intente con http

Comment: ¿Porqué no puedes? ¿Que error da?

Comment: no sale ningún error no trae la imagen                                                                               <img class="img_ref"   src="dominio.com/FOTOS/1w0as260.png" alt="">

Comment: ¿La consola del navegador no se queja? ¿No dice que no encuentra el documento, por ejemplo?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No puedes leer la carpeta ¿desde dónde, con qué?